# CSS Set <select> width equals to above <input>

Tags: html, css

I´m building an autocomplete component, but I´m having difficulties setting the `<select>` width equal to `<input>`. Here is the code:

```css
 .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .input {
      flex: 9;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .button {}
    
    .list {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 30px;
      left: 8px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='input'>
        <input type='text' placeholder='type here...' />
      </div>
      <div class='button'>
        <button type='button'>go!</button>
      </div>
      <div class='list'>
        <select size='3'>
          <option value='1'>First option</option>
          <option value='2'>Second option</option>
          <option value='3'>Third option</option>
        </select>
    
      </div>
    </div>
```

I cannot make the `<select>` component be the same width as the `<input>` component.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xt9q4s9/)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this --> https://jsfiddle.net/4xt9q4s9/1/ is correct since it's such a simple fix I would be surprised if you haven't already tried it. Could you take a look and let me know?

Comment: select { width: 100%; }

Comment: Do you need to place your '<select>' tag and 'input' tag in separate divs or it doesn't matter?

Comment: `.list select {width: 20%;}`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4xt9q4s9/4/

Comment: @Abhitalks: consider posting that as an answer, explaining how and why it works in order that the OP, and others in future, can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix, but i think we are not understanding correctly..

The Parent is the `container` with an `width: 100%;` all you need to do is set the width of the select although the input does not have a fixed width that is why your question confuses me.

The simple solution should be:

```
.list select {width: 20%;}
```

OR

```
.list select {width: 173px;}
```

**Sulotion 2**

```
.list select {width: 20%;}
.input input {width: 20%;}
```

(might want to add a bit of padding for the input, but get the idea..)

Comment: You´re sure about the parent stuff. The width must be equal not to parent, but to input. I´m fix that on post. But your code is setting the select width equals to div (including the button). I need width equal the input.